# How to check if required fields are filled in or not?

Tags: php, html, required

Using core PHP only and nothing else, like JavaScript or clientside programming, I need PHP to check if the form's required fields are filled in or not, and display error message if missed. I need to check using procedural style programming as I'm not into OOP yet and don't understand it.

Html Form

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
Searchengine Result Page
</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method = 'POST' action = "">
<label for='submission_id'>submission_id</label>
<input type='text' name='submission_id' id='submission_id'>
<br>
<label for='website_age'>website_age</label>
<input type='text' name='website_age' id='website_age'>
<br>
<label for='url'>url</label>
<input type='url' name='url' id='url' required>
<br>
<label for='anchor'>anchor</label>
<input type='text' name='anchor' id='anchor' required>
<br>
<label for='description'>description</label>
<input type='text' name='description' id='description' required>
<br>
<label for='keyphrase'>keyphrase</label>
<input type='text' name='keyphrase' id='keyphrase' required>
<br>
<label for='keyword'>keyword</label>
<input type='text' name='keyword' id='keyword' required>
<br>
<button type='submit'>Search!</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Php Form Validator

```php
<?php
$ints_labels = array('submission_id','website_age');
$strings_labels = array('url','anchor','description','keyphrase','keyword');
$required_labels = array('url','anchor','description','keyphrase','keyword');

$required_labels_count = count($required_labels);

for($i=0; $i!=$required_labels_count; $i++)
{
    if(!ISSET(in_array(($_POST['$required_labels[$i]']),$required_labels))) //Incomplete line as I     don't know how to complete the code here.
    {
        echo 'You must fill-in the field' .'Missed field\'s label goes here'; //How to echo the missed field's label here ?
    }
}

?>
```

I know I need to check against associated array values as it would be easier and less code, but I don't know how to do it.
Notice my error echo. It's incomplete as I don't know how to write that peace of code.
How would you check with the shortest possible code using procedural style?
Anything else I need to know?

NOTE: I do not want to be manually typing each `$_POST[]` to check if the required ones are filled in or not. I need PHP to loop through the `$required_labels[]` array and check. Or if you know of any shorter way of checking without looping then I want to know.

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

First we will have an empty `$errors` array, and then we will apply the validations, and if any of them fails, we will populate the `$errors`.

Finally using a helper function `errorsPrinter` we will print the errors under their labels.

For you PHP validation part use the below code. Note that I also added the part to validate the `string` and `int` types too.

```php
<?php

$ints_labels = array('submission_id','website_age');
$strings_labels = array('url','anchor','description','keyphrase','keyword');
$required_labels = array('url','anchor','description','keyphrase','keyword');

$inputs = $_POST;
$errors = [];

foreach($required_labels as $label) {    
    if(!isset($inputs[$label]) || empty($inputs[$label])) {
        $errors[$label] = array_merge(
            ["You must fill-in the field."],
            $errors[$label] ?? []
        );
    }
}

foreach($strings_labels as $label) {    
    if(isset($inputs[$label]) && !empty($inputs[$label]) && !is_string($inputs[$label])) {
        $errors[$label] = array_merge(
            ["This input should be string"],
            $errors[$label] ?? []
        );
    }
}


foreach($ints_labels as $label) {    
    if(isset($inputs[$label]) && !empty($inputs[$label]) && !is_int($inputs[$label])) {
        $errors[$label] = array_merge(
            ["This input should be int"],
            $errors[$label] ?? []
        );
    }
}


function errorsPrinter($errors, $key)
{
    $output = '<ul>';

    if(!isset($errors[$key])) {
        return;
    }
    foreach($errors[$key] as $error) {
        $output = $output. '<li>' . $error . '</li>';
    }

    print($output . '</ul>');
}
?>
```

inside the form you can do something like this:

```php
<form method='POST' action="">
    <?php errorsPrinter($errors, 'submission_id') ?>
    <label for='submission_id'>submission_id</label>
    <input type='text' name='submission_id' id='submission_id'>
    <br>
    <?php errorsPrinter($errors, 'website_age') ?>
    <label for='website_age'>website_age</label>
    <input type='text' name='website_age' id='website_age'>
    <br>
    <?php errorsPrinter($errors, 'url') ?>
    <label for='url'>url</label>
    <input type='url' name='url' id='url' >
    <br>
    <?php errorsPrinter($errors, 'anchor') ?>
    <label for='anchor'>anchor</label>
    <input type='text' name='anchor' id='anchor' >
    <br>
    <?php errorsPrinter($errors, 'description') ?>
    <label for='description'>description</label>
    <input type='text' name='description' id='description' >
    <br>
    <?php errorsPrinter($errors, 'keyphrase') ?>
    <label for='keyphrase'>keyphrase</label>
    <input type='text' name='keyphrase' id='keyphrase' >
    <br>
    <?php errorsPrinter($errors, 'keyword') ?>
    <label for='keyword'>keyword</label>
    <input type='text' name='keyword' id='keyword' >
    <br>
    <button type='submit'>Search!</button>
</form>
```

Note that the `errorsPrinter` is just a helper and you can remove it and use `$errors` array as you want. The sample output of errors is like this:

```php
[
    "url" => ["You must fill-in the field."],
    "anchor" => ["You must fill-in the field."],
    "description" => ["You must fill-in the field."],
    "keyphrase" => ["You must fill-in the field."],
    "keyword" => ["You must fill-in the field."],
    "website_age" => ["This input should be int"]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$errors = [];    
foreach($required_labels as $field) {
  if (!isset($_POST[$field]) || $_POST[$field] == '') {
    $errors[$field] = "{$field} cannot be empty";
    // echo "${field} cannot be empty";
  }
}
```

And then to output those errors:

```
<?php 
if (count($errors)) {
?>
  <div id='error_messages'>
    <p>Sorry, the following errors occurred:</p>
    <ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
      echo "<li>$error</li>";
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
<?php
}
```

And you could directly output the errors next to the input as well:

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" />
<?php if (isset($errors['first_name'])) echo "<div class='error_message'>{$errors['first_name']}</div>";?>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but it is not extendable. You have the `$errors` array but it only contains required errors, what if you want to do more checks and collect more errors which as I think he intends to.

Comment: Hi jshrc,
your code looks good but was automatically flagged by the system for its length. Could you add some explanations what you did here? Maybe some explanation what you could do with the `$errors` array (even if it is obvious for more experienced readers). :)